# How should I ask a polite question to my manager?

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

I found a new technology which could help me in my company. I want to send a message to my manager to have her approval to use that technology. I wrote this:

> I am reading about it and It seems useful.
>   I would like to ask you if you allow me to use it (if we see it could help us).

Do you think there is a better way to say that?

Comment: A comment on the question edit. In the initial sentence "...to have her approval..." is incorrect. Using an helper verb (have) requires a main verb. You could say "...to have her approve..." or simply "...to get her approval".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is more about how to convince your manager to try a new technology than it is about English language usage. When introducing a new technology, I find it works well to:

- explain how the company will benefit
- disclose costs and potential risks
- make it easy to try and back out if it doesn't work

For example:

> I am currently reading up on technology XYZ. It could potentially improve our productivity and communication by 25%. There is a free version available that we could try on our next project, and there is very little setup involved. May I have your approval to investigate this opportunity further?

Comment: Nice. Sounds like you have done this before. :)

Comment: @EnglishLearner Yes, I have more than once :)

Comment: I'm a manager and I would categorically say no to this request.  Part of a managers job, especially in tech, is to limit project risk.  Every time a new untried tech is used it introduces a high degree of risk.  If you wanted to approach me, then the best way is to say "Let me show you what I've been able to do with X".  That tells me that you've gone way beyond just reading about it and instead are actually diving into the details, which is where all of the dragons are.  So, drop the part about "try on our next project" as any decent tech manager wouldn't allow that.

Comment: @ChrisLively First I want to point out that this is a _English Language Learners_ question, so I didn't go through all of the possibilities of how you could approach different kinds of managers. Some managers will allow no time for research and development, which is why I worded the question the way I did - the OP framed the question in terms of asking for permission. I agree that the best approach for a new technology is to try it and see how it performs when implemented. Perhaps you could write an answer from your perspective; it could be very useful to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the modal verb "could", it would sound more politely.

> The new technology seems useful to our company.
>   I would like to know if you **could** allow me to look into it further to see if it could help us.

Answer (score 3):

I would rephrase it as follows:

> I am reading about it, and it seems useful.
>   May I ask you for your permission to try it, and see if it could help us?

Answer (score 1):

As a manager, there are two ways to approach me.

The first is:

> I came across this new technology which could help us with ***_*_**. 
>   Can I put together a small project demo project to see if it would
>   work?  I expect to spend about X days on it.

The second is:

> I came across this new technology and I put together a small demo
>   project at home.  Can I show you how it works?

---

The first approach is to request regular company time to do some research.  The second is saying that you've already spent *your own time* doing some research and want to show what you've found.

If you have the capability to research it on your own time, go that route as it shows that you are taking your career very seriously.

Now some managers will happily include whatever the latest tech is on a project without a real proof of concept.  I'm not that guy.  I want to eliminate as much risk as possible so the only way I'm going to say yes is if I see that someone has explored the good and bad things about the tech (and there are always downsides).  If you can prove to me that you really understand it then I'll allow it to be used.